# About NumPy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the difference between:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((3,))
```

and

```
import numpy as np
B = np.zeros((1,3))
```

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: look at `A.shape` and `B.shape`

Comment: The second one has a syntax error...

Comment: tcaswell: can you explain it to me? A.shape = (3,) and B.shape = (1,3)

Comment: @glglgl - It was fixed a little while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Hope these illustrate the difference in practice.

```
>>> A = np.zeros((3,))
>>> B = np.zeros((1,3))
>>> A #no column, just 1D
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> B #has one column
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> A.shape
(3,)
>>> B.shape
(1, 3)
>>> A[1]
0.0
>>> B[1] #can't do this, it will take the 2nd column, but there is only one column.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#89>", line 1, in <module>
    B[1]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
>>> B[0] #But you can take the 1st column
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> B[:,1] #take the 2nd cell, for each column
array([ 0.])
>>> B[0,1] #how to get the same result as A[1]? take the 2nd cell of the 1st col.
0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates a 1D `numpy.array` of zeros:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.zeros((3,))
>>> A
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> A[0]
0.0
>>>
```

The second creates a 2D `numpy.array` of 1 row and 3 columns, filled with zeros:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> B = np.zeros((1,3))
>>> B
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> B[0]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) and one on [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) if you want further details.

Comment: B is not a nested array it is a 2-d array.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: No it does not... `np.zeros((1, 3))` creates a 2D array of 1 row and 3 columns, filled with zeros. The "array within an array" could be a useful metaphor, but it's a very poor description of how numpy handles arrays and memory.

Comment: Ok.  I was trying to keep it simple because the OP is clearly a newbie at NumPy.  But, I guess it is better to be technical.

Answer (score 1):

A is a one-dimensional array with three elements.

B is a two-dimensional array with one row and three columns.

You could also use `C = np.zeros((3,1))` which would create a two-dimensional array with three rows and one column.

A, B, and C have the same elements -- the difference is in how they will be interpreted by later calls.  For instance some numpy calls operate on specific dimensions, or can be told to operate on a specific dimensions.  For instance sum:

```
>> np.sum(A, 0)
   3.0
>> np.sum(B, 0)
   array([ 1., 1., 1.])
```

They also have different behavior with matrix/tensor operations like `dot`, and also operations like `hstack` and `vstack`.

If all you are going to use is vectors, form A will usually do what you want.  The extra 'singleton' dimension (i.e., a dimension of size 1) is just extra cruft you have to keep track of.  However, if you need to interact with 2d arrays it is likely that you will have to distinguish between row vectors and column vectors.  In that case forms B and C will be useful.